# How to use Progress Bar to show another window in WPF application

Tags: c#

I want to use progress bar in WPF Windows Application,But there is no Timer control in it and I want to show another window on the form load event?
so How can I Solve this problem.?

Comment: You mean you need a timer in WPF and you want to show the ticks in a progress bar?

Comment: Why do you want to use a progress bar to show another window? Why not just show it!

Answer (score 0):

Use DispatcherTimer Class in WPF. It has almost same functionality as of Timer Control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx